# Is there any json.net equivalent for wcf datacontract namespace type resolution using typenamehandling?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

I want to use WebApi/Json.Net instead of WCF.
I'm using TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto for my serialization.

My problem is the fact that my client and server classes use a different namespace so $type does not work on deserialization.

Using WCF I can fix it using the same DataContract namespace in both client and server.

Is there any equivalent in json.net? 
If no, what would be the best way to do it?

I'm now looking on SerializationBinder and on JsonConverter but I would love having some advices on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I will use a custom JsonConverter and a custom ContractResolver with TypeNameHandling.None.

If you think there is a better thing to do, please let me know